# PHP DOM to parse all text nodes

Tags: php, parsing, dom, text, xpath

Is there a way I can retrieve an array of all plain text nodes from an HTML string?  I would like it to retrieve 'nested' elements independently, so a string like this:

```
<p>This is a <b>nested <i>HTML</i> tag<b>...</p>
```

would be retrieved as `This is a`, `nested`, `HTML`, `tag`, and `...` as separate elements.

Googling and searching SO has led me to piece together this mess of code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($contents);
$doc->loadHTML("<p>not in the brackets..</p>");
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$textnodes = $xpath->evaluate('//text()');
echo '<pre>'.print_r($textnodes,1).'</pre>';die;
```

This is giving me:

```
DOMNodeList Object
(
)
```

I've never used any DOM objects before - nor is my XPath great - so I feel very out of water here!  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot work with `print_r` or `var_dump` on DOM objects. They dont expose their internals. Your XPath is correct. Iterate the `DOMNodeList` with `foreach ($textnodes as $textnode) echo $textnode->wholeText;` to print the text. See http://codepad.viper-7.com/7lsFRG

Comment: Always the silly things!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath returns a DOMNodeList, which need to be evaluated properly. Here is an example based on  tags:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $templateDOM );
$xpath->registerNamespace( "fcm", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" );
$entries = $xpath->query( "//img" );

foreach( $entries as $entry ) {

    $newVar = array(
          'src'   => @$entry->attributes->getNamedItem( 'src' )->nodeValue, 
          'title' => $entry->attributes->getNamedItem( 'title' )->nodeValue, 
    );

    ...    

}
```